# Blank white page on running flutter app on android

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

When I run a flutter app from visual studio code I get this unresposive blank white page in my android
but when I run it from the terminal it runs well but then I cannot perform a hot reload. someone please help me on this

Comment: kindly show some code

Comment: This will happen if VS Code is unable to connect to the debugger to unpause the app (when running with the debugger, we have to start it paused so we can set breakpoints before the code starts running). Try using the [Dart: Capture Logs](https://dartcode.org/docs/logging/#capture-logs-command) command to capture a log and file an issue on GitHub.